# Не работает cors в nodejs socket

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io, cors

У меня есть инициализация express и socket io сервера я пытаюсь сделать запрос на порт 3333 с порта 3000, но у меня ничего не выходит, почему?

```
import * as http from 'http';
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import cors from "cors";
import express from "express";
import { Server } from "socket.io";

dotenv.config();

const PORT = process.env.PORT ||3333;

const app = express();

app.use(cors())

const server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`));
const io = new Server(server);

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log("123")
})
```

Ошибка:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3333/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NqQ_8CK' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Так же пробовал указывать настройки для cors

```
const corsOptions = {
    origin:'http://localhost:3000',         
    optionSuccessStatus:200
}

или

const corsOptions = {
    origin:'*',          
    optionSuccessStatus:200
}
```

с этими настройками в других моих приложениях проблем не было.

Answer (score 0):

**UPD**

Мне помогло указание cors при создании socket сервера

```
const io = new Server(server, {cors: {origin: "*"}});
```

Comment: `app.use(cors({
    credentials: true,
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000'
}));`